# Spring Cloud Config behavior difference between docker-compose and Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a basic spring cloud microservice that I use in my application. Each of the config and discovery services are built as docker containers and when I use `docker-compose` to run them, everything works fine in that the config server loads the properties files from the mounted directly and displays the below in the logs:

```
2021-11-16 14:29:51.691  INFO 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-16 14:29:51.691  INFO 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-16 14:29:51.713  INFO 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 22 ms
2021-11-16 14:29:51.920  INFO 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/data/application-container.properties
web-configuration-1  | 2021-11-16 14:29:51.921  INFO 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/data/hazelcast-service.properties
```

When I run the same container inside kubernetes, the container comes up fine but doesn't load the property files. I read somewhere that the profile needs to be native which I confirmed is native.

As a result, when my discovery service comes it doesn't get the port # assigned and so starts up on random port. Any idea what could be causing this container running in kubernetes not loading these application properties?

Comment: Please add information about your Kubernetes cluster - how it was deployed, its version. How you mount your properties files to use them in pod?

Comment: Apologies. The issue is resolved. I am using minikube which adds a layer between the host and the actual docker containers so when i tried to mount the local folder, it was actually mounting the folder from minikube instance which was empty.  i fixed by including the code as part of the container itself. thank you for checking in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

@sg1973 uses minikube which adds a layer between the host and the actual docker containers. Due to this, when trying to mount the local folder, it was actually mounting the folder from minikube instance, which was empty.

The problem was fixed by including the code as part of the container itself.